# Add title to image post

Tags: post-thumbnails, get-the-title

I can't add the title on a featured image in the recent posts.

try this but only get the alt

```
<?php           
$default_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )),
    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )),
);
$pages = wp_get_recent_posts(); 
?> 
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page["ID"],'',$default_attr); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**EDIT OUTPUT FIXED:**

```
<ul>
    <li><img width="650" height="383" title="" alt="" class="attachment- wp-post-image" src=""></li>
    <li><img width="650" height="383" title="" alt="" class="attachment- wp-post-image" src=""></li>
    <li><img width="650" height="383" title="" alt="" class="attachment- wp-post-image" src=""></li>
    <li><img width="650" height="383" title="" alt="" class="attachment- wp-post-image" src=""></li>
</ul>
```

Any idea?

**SOLUTION**

This work for me

```
<?php $pages = wp_get_recent_posts(); ?> 
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <?php
        $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID );
        $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );

        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page["ID"],'', array( 'title' => esc_attr($page["post_title"]), 'data-thumb' => $url)); ?><br />
            <?php echo esc_attr($page["post_title"]) ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the actual HTML output? Does the Post in question *have* a Post Title?

Comment: i need it to a nivo slider (no plug in), so this is the final output i can add a link to post.

Comment: Please **edit your post**, and paste in a representative example of the rendered output (e.g. from your browser source).

Comment: done @Chip Bennett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't see any of those parameters in the parameter list for [`wp_get_recent_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts).

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include' => ,
    'exclude' => ,
    'meta_key' => ,
    'meta_value' =>,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft, publish, future, pending, private',
    'suppress_filters' => true );
```

Compare to your code.

```
    $default_attr = array(
        'src'   => $src,
        'class' => "attachment-$size",
        'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )),
        'title' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )),
    );
    $pages = wp_get_recent_posts($default_attr);
```

Those are the correct parameters for [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)...

```
// straight from the Codex
$default_attr = array(
    'src'   => $src,
    'class' => "attachment-$size",
    'alt'   => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_excerpt )),
    'title' => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title )),
);
```

... but you aren't using them for that, which looks like the mistake to me. Your call to `get_the_post_thumbnail` needs to be...

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page["ID"],'',$default_attr);
```

.. and you don't need to passing those parameters to `wp_get_recent_posts`.

It looks like you have copied the default parameters from the Codex and are attempting to use those unaltered. That is not going to work. Those default parameters depend on things that are not set for your code. Secondly, you only need to pass the parameters that you want to change. For example...

```
// straight from the Codex
$default_attr = array(
    'class' => "nifty-class", // this is added to other classes. It does not replace them
    'alt'   => "I am soooo alt",
    'title' => "And I am a title",
);
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page["ID"],'',$default_attr);
```

If you pass a `src` it has to be correct or the image will not load.

Comment: Edit the entry according to your comments, and this was the result.

Comment: umm... what was the result?

Comment: a blank list `<li><img width="650" height="383" title="" alt="" class="attachment- wp-post-image" src=""></li>` no src no alt no title at least print the title

Comment: The code works. The parameters you are setting are wrong. They are empty or broken. For example, `attachment-` is what would happen with your parameters if `$size` were not set in your code before you try to use the variable. Save yourself trouble and only set the values you need-- the title, I think.

Comment: @Krathos : see the edit.

Comment: yep! this work fine to! thanks @s_ha_dum i need to find how to get the src because i want add data-thumb and print src =D

Answer (score 0):

To solve you problem

```
<?php           
$pages = wp_get_recent_posts(); 
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
        <li>
            <?php
            $attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID );
            $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
            ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $attachment->guid; ?>" title ="<?php echo $attachment->post_title ; ?>" alt="image for: <?php echo $attachment->post_title ; ?>" />
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
?>
```

Comment: didn't work =( only show the alt

Comment: did you use it in loop?

Comment: yes of course, but only show the alt no title

Comment: hey Krathos, check i edit my answer

Comment: Thanks! it works... but just i used part of your code... still had a problem... in one moment i gonna update the post worked

Comment: best of luck........:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at your `echo`: you'll need to add your `$default_attr` to your `get_the_post_thumbnail`:

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $default_attr ); ?>
```

There are also a lot of good examples at the Codex: [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

UPDATE: As @Kratos pointed out, the code aboce will only echo the image (the title of `$default_attr` only appears in the classname) but not as a `title` attribute.

The solution to this is to set the title attribute with [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail):

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, array( 'title' => esc_attr( $page["post_title"] ) ) ); ?>
```

Comment: also didn't work... the output is this
`<img class="attachment- wp-post-image" width="650" height="383" alt="Donec vitae ullamcorper odio" src="http://doamin.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/04.jpg">`

Comment: @Krathos Sorry, you're right! You'll get it this way: `<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, array( 'title' => 'Your Title' ) ); ?> `

Comment: This also helped me... but i change `array( 'title' => 'Your Title' )` to `array( 'title' => esc_attr($page["post_title"]))` to get the post title and it work =D

Comment: Very nice, I added your code to the answer :)